# visual studio 2012 countious folder and files hiding after close project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have project in visual studio 2012 and I am adding files and folder but the problem is files and folder is hiding then i  click show all files button and then right click the folder and files and **include the project in my project**
and files and folder show fine but when i close the project files and folder again hide.Whats the problem with my visual studio 2012.I am using professional version visual studio 2012.

Comment: Its funny !! Double check all things, might be your **.csproj** file is replacing, also check for **.sln** file, try to remove **.csproj.user** and then rebuild..

Comment: even if i created a new project and create folders in it and close the project and open the project.Files is not showing

Comment: Install all latest updates of VS 2012